# Unable To Clean Incorrect Geometries with Grass?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, topology

**Software:**

QGIS 2.18.10

GRASS GIS 7.2.1

GitHub Repository Link: [Police](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/Police/)

---

---

Having difficulty fixing incorrect geometries for *nypolicew84.zip* shapefile (check GitHub link)

Errors when using GRASS to fix issue. Is there anything I am missing? Or is there a more straight-forward way to fix shapefile. Please assist.

QGIS file also in GitHub

Below are the steps:

#### 1. Open Topology Checker

[image]

#### 2. Click on Configuration

[image]

#### 3. Select `must not have invalid geometries`

[image]

#### 4. Rule gets added

[image]

#### 5. Click on `Validate All`

[image]

#### 6. Error Found

[image]

#### 7. Zoom in to see all errors

[image]

#### 8. Open GRASS GIS and set location

[image]

#### 9. Follow prompts to set location. Kept at default

[image]

#### 10. Keep EPSG

[image]

#### 11. Select EPSG 4326

[image]

#### 12. Get Unlabeled Error

[image]

#### 13. `Finish` is grayed out

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at your project and found a couple of polygon errors, using **Check Validity** tool (in Processing, under QGIS Geoalgorithms). That gives more detailed error messages than **topology checker plugin** . It also splits your layer into valid and invalid geometries.

The Topology Checker plugin checks a lot of things, but doesn't appear to give a more detailed reason WHY a geometry is invalid.

Looking at the "Invalid output" layer, two of the precincts have the following errors:-

```
Ring 0 has less than 4 points
```

You might want to try running **v.clean** (from Processing, rather than the GRASS GUI). I tend to use processing when I can, as it handles a lot of the setup (projections, regions) for you.

After running v.clean with default settings, then running topology checker on the output, the geometries show up as clean.

#### Edit

After running this fix the `Duplicate ...` errors by going to  **Vector - Geometry tools - Singleparts to multipart**

Comment: Hello @steven-kay I get error `This algorithm cannot be run :-( 
GRASS folder is not configured. Please configure it before running GRASS algorithms.` When I google it says enable Grass plugin, but when I search the plugin is not in QGIS. Here is link, https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/grass/grass_setup.html

Comment: @Rhonda: To my knowledge QGIS searches in the path for "grass73", then "grass72", then "grass70" (in this order). Are you sure that GRASS GIS 7 is installed on your system?

Comment: @markusN Yes, GRASS GIS 7 installed along with QGIS. I installed `QGIS Standalone Installer Version 2.18 (64 bit) from http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html. Or is there another website/variant of QGIS?

Comment: @markusN I created separate question for GRASS. If possible, please answer, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246722/how-to-properly-install-grass

Comment: See https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16777 . There is a known bug in the QGIS 2.18.10 standalone installer, that affects GRASS GUI too. Try OSGEO4W setup as an alternative.

Comment: @steven-kay I added the following to your solution, After running this fix the `Duplicate ... `errors by going to **Vector - Geometry tools - Singleparts to multipart**