# Installing GRASS with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation, topology

I followed the steps suggested by @kazuhito and it is set to the GRASS folder.

However when I close, I get error message.

#### GRASS Folder is set

[image]

#### Error message when attempting to Close - have to Cancel instead

[image]

---

---

#### Original Question

This is branched off from [Unable To Clean Incorrect Geometries with Grass](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246549/unable-to-clean-incorrect-geometries-with-grass/246554?noredirect=1#comment386863_246554)

I installed `QGIS Standalone Installer Version 2.18 (64 bit) from [QGIS Download Website](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).

Then I went to [GRASS GIS Download page](https://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/ms-windows/) to install `GRASS GIS 7.2.1 (current stable)`

No matter what I try, every time I run v.clean I get same error:

> This algorithm cannot be run :-( GRASS folder is not configured.
> Please configure it before running GRASS algorithms.

How to fix this?

Comment: Could you open `Processing | Options | Providers | GRASS GIS 7 commands | GRASS7 folder` and check if it is set to your grass-7.2.1 folder?

Comment: @Kazuhito Yes, GRASS folder is set to `grass-7.2.1 `, however I get error when trying to close the dialog. Have to cancel instead. Please see updated questions.

Comment: Please try to revise your question with responses to each clarification sought rather than trying to turn it into a conversation with your commenters.  That way what you are asking, and the answer(s) supplied are much clearer.  Our focussed Q&A format is introduced in the 2-minute [Tour] of the site that all of its users are expected to have taken.

Comment: I think the error itself is not related to GRASS7, but to older GRASS6. Could you open `GRASS commands` (just below GRASS 7 commands) and deactivate it?

Comment: There is a bug in the current QGIS release, see https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16777. You can switch back to QGIS 2.18.9 until the bug is fixed.

Comment: @AndreJ Your solution worked. If you post answer I will mark as solution. Thanks!

Comment: The question is closed as a duplicate, so no answer possible. You can upvote the answer in the duplicate.